# ¿Cómo mostrar donde yo quiera la descripción del producto individual Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theme

Me gustaría que sólo la Descripción del producto, es decir, ni los productos relacionados ni las valoraciones del producto, se mostrase en mi plantilla debajo del título.

Estoy modificando la plantilla content-single-product, y se que la descripción está dentro de after_single_product_summary, pero no encuentro tutoriales o referencias sobre cómo extraer sólo el contenido de la descripción.

Lo que quiero modificar está aquí, dentro de la *woocommerce_after_single_product_summary*:

```
<?php
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_after_single_product_summary.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_upsell_display - 15
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_related_products - 20
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );
    ?>
```

¡Muchas gracias por su apoyo!

Comment: No se entiende lo que estas solicitando, No hay codigo, No hay errores y tampoco lo que haz intentado para solucionar esos errores; esta pregunta esta basada en opiniones, yo te podria responder que Si se puede, otro que No, otro diria Depende.

Comment: Podrias agregar el bloque de codigo del archivo .tpl en donde te renderiza toda la informacion del producto?

Answer (score 0):

Ya logré hacerlo, no es lo más elegante pero funciona.
Simplemente utilicé dos veces en la plantilla

```
<?php
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );
?>
```

Y con CSS oculto respectivamente lo que no quiero que se visualice.
Sería interesante si más adelante alguien conoce otro método para lograrlo.

Gracias por su apoyo.